# How to create radio buttons dynamically and default one option checked

Tags: javascript

I was trying to create dynamic radio buttons of bootstrap using javascript inside a card,

I was trying like

```js
const resultsDiv = document.querySelector("#results");
const getList = document.querySelector("#example");



getList.addEventListener("click", async(e) => {
  let results = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

  results.forEach((el, idx) => {
    //carousel
    const carouselItem = document.createElement("div");
    if (idx === 1) {
      carouselItem.classList.add("carousel-item", "active");
    }
    carouselItem.classList.add("carousel-item");

    //row below carousel
    const row = document.createElement("div");
    row.classList.add("row");

    //column for rows
    const column = document.createElement("div");
    column.classList.add("col-md-12", "mb-3");

    // card for each carousel inside column
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card");


    // card body for card
    const cardBody = document.createElement("div");
    cardBody.classList.add("card-body", "text-center");

    // card text (upload info)
    const cardTextUploadedOn = document.createElement("p");
    cardTextUploadedOn.classList.add("card-text");
    cardTextUploadedOn.innerText = "adsadad";

    const cardTextUploadedBy = document.createElement("p");
    cardTextUploadedBy.classList.add("card-text");
    cardTextUploadedBy.innerText = "adsadad";

    // show predictions

    const formGroup = document.createElement("div");
    formGroup.classList.add("form-group", "row");

    const predLabel = document.createElement("div");
    predLabel.classList.add("col-lg-12");
    predLabel.innerText = "Select";

    const dummy = document.createElement("div");
    dummy.classList.add("col-sm-10");

    formGroup.appendChild(predLabel);
    formGroup.appendChild(dummy);


    // yes / no options
    const verifyRow = document.createElement("div");
    verifyRow.classList.add("row");

    const verifyLegend = document.createElement("legend");
    verifyLegend.classList.add("col-form-label", "col-lg-12", "pt-0");
    verifyLegend.innerText = "Is this prediction correct ?";

    const verifyDummy = document.createElement("div");
    verifyDummy.classList.add("col-sm-10");

    const verifyYesFormCheck = document.createElement("div");
    verifyYesFormCheck.classList.add("form-check");

    const verifyNoFormCheck = document.createElement("div");
    verifyNoFormCheck.classList.add("form-check");

    const yesInput = document.createElement("input");
    yesInput.classList.add("form-check-input", "verify-yes");
    yesInput.type = "radio";
    yesInput.checked = true;
    yesInput.name = "choosePred";
    yesInput.value = "Yes";

    const verifyYesLabel = document.createElement("label");
    verifyYesLabel.classList.add("form-check-label", "verify-no");
    verifyYesLabel.innerText = "Yes";

    const verifyNoLabel = document.createElement("label");
    verifyNoLabel.classList.add("form-check-label");
    verifyNoLabel.innerText = "No";

    const noInput = document.createElement("input");
    noInput.classList.add("form-check-input");
    noInput.type = "radio";
    noInput.name = "choosePred";
    noInput.value = "No";

    // yes no options end

    resultsDiv.appendChild(carouselItem);
    carouselItem.appendChild(row);
    row.appendChild(column);
    column.appendChild(card);
    card.appendChild(cardBody);
    cardBody.appendChild(cardTextUploadedBy);
    cardBody.appendChild(cardTextUploadedOn);
    cardBody.appendChild(formGroup);
    cardBody.appendChild(verifyRow);
    verifyRow.appendChild(verifyLegend);
    verifyRow.appendChild(verifyDummy);
    verifyDummy.appendChild(verifyYesFormCheck);
    verifyDummy.appendChild(verifyNoFormCheck);
    verifyYesFormCheck.appendChild(yesInput);
    verifyYesFormCheck.appendChild(verifyYesLabel);
    verifyNoFormCheck.appendChild(noInput);
    verifyNoFormCheck.appendChild(verifyNoLabel);


  });
  const verifyYesRadios = document.querySelectorAll(".verify-yes");
  verifyYesRadios.forEach((radio) => {
    radio.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    radio.checked = true;
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.4/cropper.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/advisory-new.css') }}" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>

  <button id="example">Show results</button>



  <section class="pt-5 pb-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row m-auto">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h3 class="mb-3">Some heading</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
          <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M1 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11.793l-3.147-3.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708l4 4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-4 4a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L13.293 8.5H1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 1 8z" />
                        </svg>
          </a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M15 8a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H2.707l3.147-3.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708-.708l-4 4a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708l4 4a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L2.707 8.5H14.5A.5.5 0 0 0 15 8z" />
                        </svg>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 m-auto shadow-lg p-3">
          <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">

            <div class="carousel-inner" id="results">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

when I am doing so I could able to see the checked to only first carousel card (if the above is created like for e.g. 4 cards - one card inside one carousel (each card is inside a carousel)) and rest all have nothing checked

i have also tried after loop as

```
const verifyYesRadios = document.querySelectorAll(".verify-yes");
      verifyYesRadios.forEach((radio) => {
        radio.checked = true;
      });
```

even this didn't work

May I know how this can be achieved (each card will have a yes/no and yes to be checked by default) , any help is much appreciated

Comment: I try your code with a simple snippet and all work

Comment: okay sure @mplungjan

Comment: @SimoneRossaini like i was using this inside a carousel -> each carousel has one card -> and card has yes/no .... so i can see only active carousel -> card -> radio yes is checked and next carousels have nothing checked at all both yes/no

Comment: Oh so how @mplungjan said post a complete snippet with carousel too

Comment: yes sure i will try to reproduce the example

Comment: @mplungjan , Simone please can you see the snippet i have attached ... thanks

Comment: please hit on show results to view

Comment: And what is expected and actual behaviour? Also why async? What is the benefit?

Comment: expected behavior is each carousel added should have `yes` checked by default ,  @mplungjan sorry i forgot to remove , there was an API call there so i kept it so.........also may i know how can i add event listener to each of it ?

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll(".verify-yes")].forEach(radio =>  radio.checked=true)`

Comment: What event listener do you want to add to what?

Comment: @mplungjan On click i could say... I can hide and show the p tags based on yes/no of the particular carousel the event is triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all YES buttons:

```
 [...document.querySelectorAll(".verify-yes")].forEach(radio =>  radio.checked=true)
```

but is not needed if you set the checked to true when creating

Add event handler:

If you wrap the P tags in their own div, they are easier to toggle

```
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.type && tgt.type==="radio") { console.log(tgt.className)
    const hide = tgt.classList.contains("verify-no");
    [...tgt.closest(".card-body").querySelectorAll("p.card-text")].forEach(par => par.classList.toggle("d-none",hide))
  }
})
```

I had to add a verify-no class to the no

ALso I tried to use the bootstrat d-none but perhaps it only works in v5

```js
const resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");
const getList = document.getElementById("example");

document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.type && tgt.type==="radio") {
    const hide = tgt.classList.contains("verify-no");
    [...tgt.closest(".card-body").querySelectorAll("p.card-text")].forEach(par => par.classList.toggle("d-none",hide))
  }
})  

getList.addEventListener("click", e => {
  let results = ['a','b','c'];
 
      results.forEach((el,idx) => {
        //carousel
        const carouselItem = document.createElement("div");
        if (idx === 1) {
          carouselItem.classList.add("carousel-item", "active");
        }
        carouselItem.classList.add("carousel-item");

        //row below carousel
        const row = document.createElement("div");
        row.classList.add("row");

        //column for rows
        const column = document.createElement("div");
        column.classList.add("col-md-12", "mb-3");

        // card for each carousel inside column
        const card = document.createElement("div");
        card.classList.add("card");

       
        // card body for card
        const cardBody = document.createElement("div");
        cardBody.classList.add("card-body", "text-center");

        // card text (upload info)
        const cardTextUploadedOn = document.createElement("p");
        cardTextUploadedOn.classList.add("card-text");
        cardTextUploadedOn.innerText = "adsadad";

        const cardTextUploadedBy = document.createElement("p");
        cardTextUploadedBy.classList.add("card-text");
        cardTextUploadedBy.innerText = "adsadad";

        // show predictions

        const formGroup = document.createElement("div");
        formGroup.classList.add("form-group", "row");

        const predLabel = document.createElement("div");
        predLabel.classList.add("col-lg-12");
        predLabel.innerText = "Select";

        const dummy = document.createElement("div");
        dummy.classList.add("col-sm-10");

        formGroup.appendChild(predLabel);
        formGroup.appendChild(dummy);

       
        // yes / no options
        const verifyRow = document.createElement("div");
        verifyRow.classList.add("row");

        const verifyLegend = document.createElement("legend");
        verifyLegend.classList.add("col-form-label", "col-lg-12", "pt-0");
        verifyLegend.innerText = "Is this prediction correct ?";

        const verifyDummy = document.createElement("div");
        verifyDummy.classList.add("col-sm-10");

        const verifyYesFormCheck = document.createElement("div");
        verifyYesFormCheck.classList.add("form-check");

        const verifyNoFormCheck = document.createElement("div");
        verifyNoFormCheck.classList.add("form-check");

        const yesInput = document.createElement("input");
        yesInput.classList.add("form-check-input", "verify-yes");
        yesInput.type = "radio";
        yesInput.checked = true; // this will check it
        yesInput.name = "choosePred" + idx;
        yesInput.value = "Yes";

        const verifyYesLabel = document.createElement("label");
        verifyYesLabel.classList.add("form-check-label", "verify-yes");
        verifyYesLabel.innerText = "Yes";

        const verifyNoLabel = document.createElement("label");
        verifyNoLabel.classList.add("form-check-label", "verify-no");
        verifyNoLabel.innerText = "No";

        const noInput = document.createElement("input");
        noInput.classList.add("form-check-input", "verify-no");
        noInput.type = "radio";
        noInput.name = "choosePred" + idx;
        noInput.value = "No";

        // yes no options end

        resultsDiv.appendChild(carouselItem);
        carouselItem.appendChild(row);
        row.appendChild(column);
        column.appendChild(card);
        card.appendChild(cardBody);
        cardBody.appendChild(cardTextUploadedBy);
        cardBody.appendChild(cardTextUploadedOn);
        cardBody.appendChild(formGroup);
        cardBody.appendChild(verifyRow);
        verifyRow.appendChild(verifyLegend);
        verifyRow.appendChild(verifyDummy);
        verifyDummy.appendChild(verifyYesFormCheck);
        verifyDummy.appendChild(verifyNoFormCheck);
        verifyYesFormCheck.appendChild(yesInput);
        verifyYesFormCheck.appendChild(verifyYesLabel);
        verifyNoFormCheck.appendChild(noInput);
        verifyNoFormCheck.appendChild(verifyNoLabel);


      });
      // if needed later
      // [...document.querySelectorAll(".verify-yes")].forEach(radio =>  radio.checked=true)
    })
```

```css
.d-none { display:none }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.4/cropper.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/advisory-new.css') }}" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>

     <button id="example">Show results</button>

    

    <section class="pt-5 pb-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row m-auto">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <h3 class="mb-3">Some heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 text-right">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button"
                        data-slide="prev">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M1 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11.793l-3.147-3.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708l4 4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-4 4a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L13.293 8.5H1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 1 8z" />
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-arrow-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M15 8a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H2.707l3.147-3.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708-.708l-4 4a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708l4 4a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L2.707 8.5H14.5A.5.5 0 0 0 15 8z" />
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 m-auto shadow-lg p-3">
                    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">

                        <div class="carousel-inner" id="results">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @mplungjan , so if i want to get the whole data of each carousel , say with a button at the end of each carousel , i could do with get `closest` carousel item and get all the values w.r.t the `item`  ... am i right ? also is it possible to remove the respective carousel item at the same time the button clicked and make the other carosuel active ?  sorry for a huge number of queries ! :(

Comment: Yes. You can use the closest to get to the `".card"` and remove or hide it

Comment: is that if we remove one item (carousel-item) , the next item appears as `active` ? guess it should be some work

Comment: may i know how could I add one select to each carousel item ? i tried adding but options get added to only one carousel item

Comment: I have no idea. Ask a new question and show what you are trying to do in a [mcve]

Comment: hey somehow i have made that to add ... sure i would add another .. i understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Radio input sets should have different names. I added index number to radio input set names and it works. In this case an input set is a couple of radio inputs ("Yes" and "No") in a carousel. They share the same name, therefore they are the same radio set/group.

```js
const resultsDiv = document.querySelector("#results");
const getList = document.querySelector("#example");

  

getList.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
  let results = ['a','b','c'];
 
      results.forEach((el,idx) => {
        //carousel
        const carouselItem = document.createElement("div");
        if (idx === 1) {
          carouselItem.classList.add("carousel-item", "active");
        }
        carouselItem.classList.add("carousel-item");

        //row below carousel
        const row = document.createElement("div");
        row.classList.add("row");

        //column for rows
        const column = document.createElement("div");
        column.classList.add("col-md-12", "mb-3");

        // card for each carousel inside column
        const card = document.createElement("div");
        card.classList.add("card");

       
        // card body for card
        const cardBody = document.createElement("div");
        cardBody.classList.add("card-body", "text-center");

        // card text (upload info)
        const cardTextUploadedOn = document.createElement("p");
        cardTextUploadedOn.classList.add("card-text");
        cardTextUploadedOn.innerText = "adsadad";

        const cardTextUploadedBy = document.createElement("p");
        cardTextUploadedBy.classList.add("card-text");
        cardTextUploadedBy.innerText = "adsadad";

        // show predictions

        const formGroup = document.createElement("div");
        formGroup.classList.add("form-group", "row");

        const predLabel = document.createElement("div");
        predLabel.classList.add("col-lg-12");
        predLabel.innerText = "Select";

        const dummy = document.createElement("div");
        dummy.classList.add("col-sm-10");

        formGroup.appendChild(predLabel);
        formGroup.appendChild(dummy);

       
        // yes / no options
        const verifyRow = document.createElement("div");
        verifyRow.classList.add("row");

        const verifyLegend = document.createElement("legend");
        verifyLegend.classList.add("col-form-label", "col-lg-12", "pt-0");
        verifyLegend.innerText = "Is this prediction correct ?";

        const verifyDummy = document.createElement("div");
        verifyDummy.classList.add("col-sm-10");

        const verifyYesFormCheck = document.createElement("div");
        verifyYesFormCheck.classList.add("form-check");

        const verifyNoFormCheck = document.createElement("div");
        verifyNoFormCheck.classList.add("form-check");

        const yesInput = document.createElement("input");
        yesInput.classList.add("form-check-input", "verify-yes");
        yesInput.type = "radio";
        yesInput.checked = true;
        yesInput.name = "choosePred" + idx;
        yesInput.value = "Yes";

        const verifyYesLabel = document.createElement("label");
        verifyYesLabel.classList.add("form-check-label", "verify-no");
        verifyYesLabel.innerText = "Yes";

        const verifyNoLabel = document.createElement("label");
        verifyNoLabel.classList.add("form-check-label");
        verifyNoLabel.innerText = "No";

        const noInput = document.createElement("input");
        noInput.classList.add("form-check-input");
        noInput.type = "radio";
        noInput.name = "choosePred" + idx;
        noInput.value = "No";

        // yes no options end

        resultsDiv.appendChild(carouselItem);
        carouselItem.appendChild(row);
        row.appendChild(column);
        column.appendChild(card);
        card.appendChild(cardBody);
        cardBody.appendChild(cardTextUploadedBy);
        cardBody.appendChild(cardTextUploadedOn);
        cardBody.appendChild(formGroup);
        cardBody.appendChild(verifyRow);
        verifyRow.appendChild(verifyLegend);
        verifyRow.appendChild(verifyDummy);
        verifyDummy.appendChild(verifyYesFormCheck);
        verifyDummy.appendChild(verifyNoFormCheck);
        verifyYesFormCheck.appendChild(yesInput);
        verifyYesFormCheck.appendChild(verifyYesLabel);
        verifyNoFormCheck.appendChild(noInput);
        verifyNoFormCheck.appendChild(verifyNoLabel);


      });
      const verifyYesRadios = document.querySelectorAll(".verify-yes");
      verifyYesRadios.forEach((radio) => {
        radio.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
        radio.checked = true;
      });
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.4/cropper.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/advisory-new.css') }}" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>

     <button id="example">Show results</button>

    

    <section class="pt-5 pb-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row m-auto">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <h3 class="mb-3">Some heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 text-right">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button"
                        data-slide="prev">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M1 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11.793l-3.147-3.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708l4 4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-4 4a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L13.293 8.5H1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 1 8z" />
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-arrow-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M15 8a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H2.707l3.147-3.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708-.708l-4 4a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708l4 4a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L2.707 8.5H14.5A.5.5 0 0 0 15 8z" />
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 m-auto shadow-lg p-3">
                    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">

                        <div class="carousel-inner" id="results">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: great !! so if i had to remove one of the carousel here ? this vl not affect any part ryt ?

Comment: Thanks a ton mate , may i know if we can add event listeners to each of it \?

Comment: "radio inputs should have different names" is incorrect. SETS of radio inputs should have different names. EACH radio in each set has to have the SAME name, or their functionality are no longer radio buttons

Comment: @mplungjan may i know how can i add event listeners to the set of radio inputs here ?

Comment: You should delegate instead of having an event listener per thing

Comment: @mplungjan , sorry ,  can you give an example please ?

Comment: Dainius did the correct thing, each SET has a different name.

Comment: This DOES check all YES buttons: `[...document.querySelectorAll(".verify-yes")].forEach(radio =>  radio.checked=true)`